# Manipular XML com Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml

Estou com uma dúvida e já busquei muito e mesmo assim não consegui resolver.

Tenho um XML com uma tag chamada `<child id='minhatag'/>`.
Preciso fazer com que o javascript faça a leitura dessa tag e consiga me retornar o valor do ID da tag child para que o valor eu consiga colocar em um botão, porque minha tela terá varios botões que serão apresentados de acordo com os valores das "Child's ID's".
OBS: Vale lembrar que serão varias childs por exemplo:

```
<child id='child1'/>
<child id='child2'/>
<child id='child3'/>
```

E o XML ficará na mesma estrutura de pastas do código ou seja não vai ser um acesso via URL, pelo menos não a princípio.

Comment: Isso esta junto com os elementos HTML? é uma result de uma chamada AJAX?

Comment: Mas qual o valor do `child`?

Comment: @Guilherme Lautert não os valores no CHILD estão em um arquivo separado.

Comment: @MagicHat a child não tem um valor em si eu preciso ter o retorno do valor do ID da child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo para fazer isso, porém precisa de um pai para cosneguir fazer o parse:

```js
var xml, parser, xmlDoc;
text = "<children><child id='child1'/>" +
       "<child id='child2'/>" +
       "<child id='child3'/></children>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("children")[0].childNodes.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value.id);
});
```

Comment: mas como faria no caso pra acessar um xml que está em um arquivo dele, porque dessa forma que você apresentou ele está puxando itens fixos dentro do próprio script na index certo ? Seria como se ele estivesse em um XML chamado "child.xml" por exemplo e todo o código estará lá.

Comment: esqueci mesmo de comendar eles tem um pai, no caso o <children><child id="child1" /></children> basicamente

Comment: Sem problemas, só trocar o seletor do pai de childs para children. Foi até uma falha do meu inglês rs

Comment: e quanto a parte do acesso a um arquivo xml e não dentro da própria estrutura do script no js ?

Comment: Aqui está uma pergunta com uma ótima resposta para de ajudar. Já que o foco dessa pergunta não foi como ler a partir de um arquivo: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: valeu com sua resposta consegui um resultado satisfatorio para questão, vou abrir outra pergunta pra um outro problema que surgiu. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tipo assim:

```js
var childs = document.getElementsByTagName("child");
for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
  console.log(childs[i].id);
}
```

```html
    <child id='child1'/>
    <child id='child2'/>
    <child id='child3'/>
```